# Identifying piano notation symbol in Chopin Mazurka

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, ornaments, chopin

I'm trying to identify what this symbol is (circled in pencil) in the sheet music for Mazurka no.4 op.17 by Chopin. It looks like two connected diamond shapes, and I can't find an explanation of it anywhere.

[image: Mazurka no.4 op.17 by Chopin]

Comment: Other sources have an upper mordent there, so either this is an alternative symbol, or it's badly printed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbxmca163Nc&t=1m59s

Comment: I also vote for upper mordent, albeit an unclearly engraved / printed one

Comment: What measure?  Have you compared the 3 or 4 editions at imslp.org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I grabbed a file from [imslp.org](http://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/7/73/IMSLP368705-PMLP02281-Chopin_-_Opus_17_-_Cortot_french.pdf)  and found your measure.  It is a simple mordent.

[image]

Comment: Would you say that the simplified symbol as it's printed in the question is an acceptable alternative? Have you come across it before?

Comment: @YourUncleBob  I haven't seen it either, and would not recommend using it .